# How do I implement this API? It's a Builder pattern that takes generic (or trait) params

Tags: generics, rust, simulation, traits, builder

### Scenario

Imagine you're a baker. You bake different cakes using different recipes.

### Goal

You're trying to plan how many ingredients you'll need over the next 6m using your upcoming list of orders.

The challenge is, your orders aren't certain. They're based on a probability.

### Problem

I've started [hallo](https://github.com/mmmoli/hallo) – a library to run these kind of simulations. I'm stuck on how to implement the ergonomics of the API I've imagined. Here's what I have in mind:

```
struct Sugar(f32);
struct Chocolate(f32);
struct Vanilla(f32);

let brownieRecipe = RecipeBuilder::default()
    .add(Sugar(200.0))
    .add(Chocolate(10.0))
    .build();

let vanillaSponge = RecipeBuilder::default()
    .add(Sugar(300.0))
    .add(Vanilla(2.0))
    .build();

let p1 = AllocationBuilder::default()
    .recipe(brownieRecipe)
    .duration_weeks(5)
    .start_date(&(today + Duration::weeks(8)))
    .build();

let p2 = AllocationBuilder::default()
    .recipe(vanillaSponge)
    .duration_weeks(2)
    .start_date(&(today + Duration::weeks(2)))
    .build();
```

The `RecipeBuilder` builds a recipe from any number of ingredients. The `AllocationBuilder` takes a recipe and plans when it's needed.

The next step is to implement a simulation engine to plot 10k outcomes (but that's out of scope of this question).

The ingredient structs might eventually implement some trait so that they can be summed (`std::Add`?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have some trait for using the ingredients. What trait - that depends on what you need to do with them. It can be a builtin trait or a custom trait, but it is important that all ingredients (`Sugar`, `Chocolate` etc.) will implement it (I'd go with a custom trait).

Assuming you have a trait `Ingredient`, store a list of `Vec<Box<dyn Ingredient>>`. For the API to be what you described, you need the `add()` method to be defined like:

```rust
pub fn add<I: Ingredient>(&mut self, ingredient: I) -> &mut Self {
    self.ingredients.push(Box::new(ingredient));
    self
}
```

This is a convenience method: instead of needing to pass `Box<dyn Ingredient>`, you pass `impl Ingredient` and the method creates the `Box<dyn Ingredient>`. This is a very common pattern in Rust.

Comment: I feel like, to match what is required by the OP, `add` should return `self`.

Comment: You've both been super helpful. Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @chayim-friedman it certainly did but BlackBeans is right, you should edit it to return self just in case anyone else comes over to copy/paste the snippet.

Once you've done that, I'll delete my answer below.

Comment: @mmmoli Done. I thought the question was specifically about the generics so I didn't bother.

Comment: All credit to you @chayim-friedman